# A hue with a view

Tags: steganography

An optimistic perception of this image might help you decipher this thing that just won't wait. The answer might depend on what kind of glasses you decide to look through or which pill you take (metaphorically speaking, of course).

[image: It won't wait...]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is the answer

> **Time** ?

Explanation:

> If we seperate the pixels of the image into the RGB color space and extract only the red byte and then view that as a grayscale image, we get the following:
>  [image]

The following hints towards this answer are given in the text:

> Looking at the world trough [rose-colored glasses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rose-colored_glasses) means that you have an optimistic perception of things. Getting an unpleasant truth revealed to you can be referred to as taking a [red pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_pill_and_blue_pill).
>  [image]
>  The answer **Time** also fits in the sense that it *does not wait*.

---

There is hinted that we should be able to see more.

> Seperating the other two color channels we obtain the following.
>  Green: [image]
>  Blue: [image]
>  Something might still be written here. Maybe roman numerals?

Comment: "The answer might depend on what kind of glasses you decide to look through" - Maybe there's something more going on?

Comment: Since you did the dirty work already, why don't you also try to rot13 qb gur fnzr sbe oyhr naq rira terra

Comment: It is a bit one sided, but I like how you think.

Comment: Considering "gvzr naq gvqr jnvg sbe ab zna" and I feel like I see the latter by squinting a little, maybe that's the second target?